# How to change page numbering to be adjusted with text

Tags: numbering, text, page

I was in need of having page numbering on the bottom right of the page. Achieved that by using following code:

```
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

After that I've encountered a little problem. Page number isn't adjusted to text properly, which is visible there:

[image: screen]

So my question is - what should I do to get effect which is shown under "Desired:" bar in my screen?

Thanks in advance for help!

Edit: Additional information, full code:

```
%& --translate-file=utf8
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{2018}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4.2cm, right=4.2cm, top=5cm, bottom=5cm, headsep=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,labelfont=bf,textfont=up]{caption}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{3cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1.5cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.5cm}
\linespread{1.5}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
[...]
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
[...]
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Wstęp}
\subsection{Cel Pracy}
[...]
\end{document}
```

Comment: we cant help you if you not provide more information about your document. please, provide small, but complete document which show your problem beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` with some dummy text in it. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: Sorry for incomplete question, just added my full code. Thanks for suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I think you did a little mess in your preamble, you set your page with `fancyhdr` and *afterwards* you modified your page layout.

You should load `geometry` *before* `fancyhdr` setting. Moreover I think this instructions:

```
\addtolength{\textwidth}{3cm}
\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1.5cm}
\addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.5cm}
```

are useless, if you correctly set `geometry` parameters.

In my solution, I loaded the useful package `showframe`, which makes the page margins visible, hence it is very handy in your case (obviously it is for testing purpose only, delete it after having correctly set your page dimensions).

(I used the `mwe` package only to have some text to fill the pages, of course you don't need it. In your actual final document, do not use the code lines marked with `<--- for testing purpose only`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{polski}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, left=4.2cm, right=4.2cm, top=5cm, bottom=5cm, headsep=1.5cm]{geometry}
%\addtolength{\textwidth}{3cm}
%\addtolength{\hoffset}{-1.5cm}
%\addtolength{\textheight}{3cm}
%\addtolength{\voffset}{-1.5cm}
\linespread{1.5}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{title}
\author{author}
\date{2018}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\fancyhf{}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,labelfont=bf,textfont=up]{caption}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{mwe}% <--- for testing purpose only
\usepackage{showframe}% <--- for testing purpose only
\begin{document}
    \begin{titlepage}
        [...]
    \end{titlepage}
    \newpage
    [...]
    \newpage
    \tableofcontents
    \newpage
    \section{Wstęp}
    \subsection{Cel Pracy}
    [...]
    \blindtext[30]% <--- for testing purpose only
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why won't you just pass `showframe` option to the `geometry` package?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Because it's easiest to comment, my habit